# Can you Listen for ShowBottomSheet on Close?

Tags: dart, flutter

Imagine creating a bottom sheet as follows:

```
final PersistenBottomSheetController bottomSheetController = showBottomSheet(...);
```

*How do I execute logic **upon closing** that bottom sheet?*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is a bit unidiomatic for Flutter widgets:
*`bottomSheetController.closed` returns a **`Future`** when closing the bottom sheet*, which allows for this logic:

```
bottomSheetController.closed.then((value) {
  // this callback will be executed on close
});
```

Works *with **`await`*** as well:

```
await bottomSheetController.closed;
// code below this call will get executed upon close
```

Answer (score 1):

```
final PersistentBottomSheetController<dynamic> bottomSheetController = scaffoldKey.currentState!.showBottomSheet((context) {
                 return Container();
        });
await bottomSheetController.closed.then((value) {
// the code for working on drawer close
});
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?